# How to handle lists when assoc-in/get-in etc

Tags: clojure

I started with a csv-file. I have slurped it and added some structure with `partition-by` and sorted with `sort-by`. But now I'd like to add values to keep track of processing. But `get-in` and `assoc-in` don't like lists. And although I haven't added lists the `partition-by` seems to like them.

So, how to get out of this situation? Is there a way to transform all lists inside a structure to vectors or an alternative version of `partition-by` that isn't such a crybaby about lists or do I need to rethink my solution somehow? :-)

A simple example of a structure

```
(sort '(1 2 3 4 5))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to transform the lists and then use the associative interface, [`clojure.walk`](https://www.conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/1.8.0/clj/clojure.walk) has utilities that allow you to do that transformation on arbitrarily nested structures.

```
(let[my-nested-structure {:foo '(1 2 4) '(0) :bar :baz {42 '()}}]
  (clojure.walk/postwalk #(if (list? %) (vec %) %) my-nested-structure))
;; => {:foo [1 2 4], [0] :bar, :baz {42 []}}
```

`postwalk` and `prewalk` are effectively the same in this instance but the difference can matter if your replacement function adds/removes sub-entries.

The [specter library](https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter) might also interest you - its `transform`, `select` and so on allow you to approach `get-in` type jobs from a slightly different direction and with that data structure agnosticism.

Comment: It seems to work for some cases but for sorted lists it seems to fail
(clojure.walk/postwalk #(if (list? %) (vec %) %) (sort '(1 2 3)))
isn't converted to a vec.

Comment: `(type (sort '(1 2 3)))` is `clojure.lang.ArraySeq` for me which is likely why. You might try using `sequential?` instead of `list?` to test whether replacement is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If your structure is a list of lists called `xs`, then you can:

```
(mapv vec xs)
```

That will give you a vector of vectors. A vector is an associative data structure (unlike a list), so `get-in` and `assoc-in` will work. However if there are more meaningful keys than the position of an element in a vector, then you might prefer to work with maps, in which case you would have a collection (vector or list) of homogeneous maps, which is a common way of working with data.

And just for verification:

```
(mapv vec '((1 2 3) (4 5 6)))
;;=> [[1 2 3] [4 5 6]]
```

Comment: As an aside, that syntax-quote is rather strange: just write `'((1 2 3) (4 5 6))`.

Comment: My structure is nested in several levels so mapv doesn't seem to cut it.